# GCP : Cloud Functions Graphs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, usage-statistics

When I execute a CF on GCP, it has graphs on 4 parameter. Invocations, Active Instance are easy to understand what data is trying to say. But I am unable to make sense of other graphs,i.e execution time & memory usage. This is a screenshot of one of our  **http triggered** CF. Can someone explain how exactly to make sense of this data? What does CF mean when it says, **99th percentile: 882.85**

***Is 99th percentile good or bad?***[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is neither good nor bad; these are the statistics for the average execution time.

See what [percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) actually means, in order to understand the chart's meaning.

eg. 99% of the observations fall below the average execution duration of 882.85 ms -

and that 1% of the observations have extreme values, which do not fall below that.

These 882.85 ms might only be suboptimal, in case the function could possibly run quicker.

It's represented alike this, so that a few extreme values won't distort the whole statistics.